# Output text file with line breaks in PHP

Tags: php, html, text-processing

I'm trying to open a text file and output its contents with the code below. The text file includes line breaks but when I echo the file its unformatted. How do I fix this?

Thanks.

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

        $fh = fopen("filename.txt", 'r');

        $pageText = fread($fh, 25000);

        echo $pageText;


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any reason for not using `fpassthru()`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To convert the plain text line breaks to html line breaks, try this:

```
    $fh = fopen("filename.txt", 'r');

    $pageText = fread($fh, 25000);

    echo nl2br($pageText);
```

Note the nl2br function wrapping the text.

Answer (score 31):

One line of code:

```
 echo nl2br( file_get_contents('file.txt') );
```

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to show the output of the file within the HTML code formatted the same way it is in the text file you can wrap your echo statement with a pair of pre tags:

```
echo "<pre>" . $pageText . "</pre>;
```

Some of the other answers look promising depending on what you are trying todo.

Answer (score 3):

For simple reads like this, I'd do something like this:

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents("filename.txt");

echo str_replace("\n","&lt;br&gt;",$fileContent);
```

This will take care of carriage return and output the text.  Unless I'm writing to a file, I don't use fopen and related functions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Before the echo, be sure to include

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
```

Comment: The output is HTML. Setting the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, with that constraint in mind, just wrap <pre> around the echoed content.

Answer (score 0):

Are you outputting to HTML or plain text? If HTML try adding a `<br>` at the end of each line. e.g.

```
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096); // Read a line.
  echo "$buffer<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get line breaks to work reading a .txt file on Apache2 and PHP 5.3.3 with MacOSX 10.6.6 and Camino, the **echo nl2br( $text);** didn't work right until I printed the file size first too.
BTW it doesn't seem to matter if the .txt file has Linux/MacOSX LF or Windows CRLF line breaks or the text encoding is UTF-8 or Windows Latin1, Camino gets it out OK.

```
<?php
$filename     = "/Users/Shared/Copies/refrain.txt";
$file_ptr     = fopen ( $filename, "r" );
$file_size    = filesize ( $filename );
$text         = fread ( $file_ptr, $file_size );
fclose ( $file_ptr );
echo ( "File size : $file_size bytes<br>&nbsp;<br>" );
echo nl2br ( $text );
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your PHP code into `<?php <YOU CODE HERE >?>`, and save it as `.php` or `.php5` (depends on your apache set up).

Answer (score -1):

Say you have an `index.php` file hosted by the web server. You want to insert some multi-line text file contents into it. That's how you do it:

```
<body>
        <div>Some multi-line message below:</div> 
        <div><?= nl2br(file_get_contents('message.txt.asc')); ?></div>
</body>
```

This `<?= ... ?>` part is just a shorthand, which instructs the web server, that it needs to be treated as a PHP `echo` argument.

Comment: While <?= is valid syntax and should not be removed from PHP as a usable shorthand, it leads to the issue of training your mind to ignore <?php and use <? only (which is deprecated in 7).  It is better for newer developers to not get into the habit of ignoring <?php for the sake of saving 8 chars in an echo.  As someone who has been writing PHP for 10+ years, it took me forever to break myself of the habit of using that specific shorthand and it is best not to get started with a known deprecated possibility if we can avoid it
<?php echo nl2br(... ...); ?>

Comment: I understand your pain. But for us people who only occasionally write bits of PHP right in the HTML, this shortcut is actually very useful.